# JS - If condition with only 1 else, does checking order affect performance?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I was working on a project and this problem popped into my head. I am not sure if there is already a post like this but I have found none.

Let say if I have this:

```
function checks(s) {
    if (s.length == 4 && s[0] == "a") {
        //action
    } else {
        //other action
    }
}
checks("a001");
checks("else");
checks("else");
checks("else");
```

and this:

```
function checkb(b) {
    if (b) {
        //action
    } else {
        //other action
    }
}
checkb(true); //Suppose i'm passing these through another function
checkb(false); //so it makes sense for me doing these
checkb(false);
checkb(false);
```

Since either way the if-statement is going to have to check once of the conditions, **if the frequency of the actions are known** (e.g. I know that the else part is performed most often). **Does checking for "not conditions" make the code run faster or does the checking of "not condition" don't even affect the performance?** (Suppose I'm building a complicated node.js server that has many of these type of functions.)

Addition question: **Do most programming languages do the same too theoretically?**

I was just wondering if it affects the performance (practically or theoretically).

Comment: It's negligible and makes no sense to optimize.

Comment: I wouldn't care of performance in this case unless this function is executed 100 million times in the loop.

Comment: I agree with @zerkms no difference at all in term of performance

Comment: I wouldn't care even if it was 100 billion times in a loop.

Comment: *Premature optimisation is the root of all evil* - Donald Knuth

Comment: `checkb(true);` has a comparison inside ... so what is the deal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, it does not effect the computation time.

**Long answer:** Most Javascript engines (Spider Monkey and V8) internally use a [Just in Time compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) which will iron over those differences during runtime.

In low level programming languages (read: C/C++ and the ilk), you *may* gain something if you are able to prevent [branch mis-predicts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor), like in [C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array), but the gain is usually worth it only if you are doing Kernel programming or doing extreme micro-optimizations.

---

Theoretically, whether it makes a difference or not depends on what kind of compiler you are looking at. If you are looking at a compiler which can learn from code traces, e.g. a Just in Time compiler, then it will make a difference if a certain pocket of code is the hot spot or not. If you are looking at static compilers, it may mean that the compiler *may* use one less clock cycle in one of the cases (either `if` or `else`) by preventing a `jmp`, but it'll depend on the compiler implementation.

Comment: thank you for giving a juicy answer. i've learnt many things today! :)